# This Google Sheets REGEXREPLACE replaces wrong values

Tags: regex, google-sheets, replace

In this [example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BmKASpQu63LOJPtcph73IlFPZMBT8XxytDHHkDRP5Ug/edit?usp=sharing) I have tried this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(TO_TEXT(A2:A20);TO_TEXT(Parameters!A2:A6);Parameters!B2:B6))
```

What I am trying to do is to check A2:A for any match in Parameters!A2:A6 and then output corresponding values in Parameters!B2:B6.

What doi I have to change?

Comment: Please post the relevant information (the regexes and texts in question) in the body of the question users and search engines don't approve a google doc that requires an account to see.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. It is a fully open document with the code I have tried. What more do you need? Furthermore I think it is unfair to down vote my. I did make an effort and I am trying to correct any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use a simple VLOOKUP? Try in cell J2 I entered

```
=ArrayFormula(iferror(if(len(A2:A); vlookup(A2:A; Parameters!A:B; 2; 0);)))
```

Or, maybe even

```
=Arrayformula(if(len(A2:A); upper(text(A2:A; "DDDD"));))
```

See if that helps?

Comment: That helped a lot. Thank You. I can't figure out how the 2nd solution works. I mean how does DDDD translate into the corresponding values in Parameter-B-columns?

Comment: It doesn't. It just shows the day (in text) of the dates in column A.

Comment: Ah!  I see. Thank You.